# How to display a score in Vpython?

Tags: python, vpython

**My Code**

```
from visual import *

class Punktecounter():
    def __init__(self,position=(0,0), score=0):
        self.counter = label(pos=position, color=color.red, text=str(score))
        self.score = score
    def scoring(self):
        self.score = self.score+1
        print (self.score)

p = Punktecounter()
while True:
    p.scoring()
    rate(1)
```

So the printing part works fine.
But the label doesn't show the score. How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label is not going to update itself, you need to do so explicitly:

```
def scoring(self):
    self.score=self.score+1
    self.label.text = str(self.score)
    print (self.score)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this

```
def scoring(self):
    self.score=self.score+1
    self.counter.text = str(self.score)
    print (self.score)
```